# Getting CultureInfo from Web.Language

Tags: 2007, development

I can get language code, e.g. "1033" for en-US by,

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://portal.loonetoones.com/default.aspx"))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(web.Language.ToString());
        // OUT put is     1033
    }
```

But I want to know it's culture e.g. I want to know if its  en-GB or en-US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code instead,

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://portal.loonetoones.com/default.aspx"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo((int)web.Language);
    Console.WriteLine(info.Name); 
}
```

For more information check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.language.aspx) out.